# How to check the value returned from a function and reiterate a loop again?

Tags: c++

I am checking whether the digits of a number are other than 1 or 0 using the function `checknumber()`. If any digit is other than 0 or 1 then ask the user to enter the number again until the digits are 0 and 1 only. After this, convert into binary and then check if the number is greater than -1 and the number is in negative then only exit.

The main function:

```
int main()
{
  int num=0,flag;
  while(num>-1){
  do
  {    
    cout<<"Enter Number: ";
    cin>>num;
  }
  while(checknumber(num,flag)==0);
  cout<<"Result in Decimal = ";
  cout << binaryToDecimal(num) << endl;
  }

}
```

This is my `checknumber()`:

```
int checknumber(int number, int flag) {
    while(number != 0){
    int val = number % 10;
    if((val != 1) && (val != 0)){
      flag=0;
      break;
    }
    else{
      flag=1;
    }
    return flag;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to put a semi-colon after your `if`?

Comment: @StephenNewell For that i am confused on how to make the condition such that the condition is satisfied.

Comment: digits of the number other than 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, You need to take a binary number as input. So, if the user enters any other string you need ask for input again. You can do that with a `do-while` loop. In `do-while` loop the logic is executed first and then the condition is checked. So, change your `main()` function like this:

```
int main()
{
  int num=0;

  do
  {    
    cout<<"Enter Number: ";
    cin>>num;
  }
  while(!checknumber(num,flag));
  
  cout<<"Result in Decimal = ";
  cout << binaryToDecimal(num) << endl;

}
```

`while(!checknumber(num,flag))` is like `while(checknumber(num,flag) == 0)`. In C/C++, `0` is evaluated as `false`. So, `!(0)` will be `true`.

Comment: But i also want to ask the user to input the number again when the digits of the number are not 0 or 1.

Comment: can you check again.

Comment: When the `checknumber()` returns 0, this will ask the user to enter number again.

Answer (score 1):

Well if I understand your code correctly, one of the issues is that your conditional in main doesn’t do anything.  You need to put in brackets { } after your if statement what you want to happen if the condition inside returns true.  If you remove the semi colon and put “{“ at the end of the if line, and then you probably want the ending bracket on the line after your final cout.
if(checknumber(num,flag)==0){

```
   cout<<"Result in Decimal = ";
   cout << binaryToDecimal(num) << endl;
}
```

Second, your while loop will break if the user inputs a 0.  I would recommend changing the while loop condition to maybe be a flag you change later once the meet the conditions for checknumber.  That way you won’t prematurely end on that edge case.  Maybe something like

```
int main()
{
  int num=1,flag=0;
  Int correctResponse = 1
  while(correctResponse>0){
     cout<<"Enter Number: ";
     cin>>num;
     if(checknumber(num,flag)==0){
         correctResponse =0;
         cout<<"Result in Decimal = ";
         cout << binaryToDecimal(num) << endl;
     }
  }
}
```

I’m not at a compiler right now, so that might not just plug in but those should resolve your issues.  Other people on this sight might have more graceful solutions.

Comment: why do you need another correctResponse variable ?

Comment: we can do like this: https://codeshare.io/adqExe. The only problem here is the code is not able to take the num input again when the digits are other than 0 or 1.